Telegram ChatID passing as client reference ID in Stripe webhooks
I am working on a telegram bot that uses stripe API for subscription. I am currently facing an issue with passing the telegram chat ID as client ID in stripe webhooks so that when I get the data from stripe I can also get the telegram Chat ID of the user to save it into my DB.
I have provided my flask code below , I dont know what am I doing wrong in this but getting Bad Request 400 Error
import logging
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import stripe
import psycopg2
from asgiref.wsgi import WsgiToAsgi

# Stripe configuration (use test key for testing)
stripe_api_key = "stripe_api_key"
endpoint_secret = 'endpoint_secret'  

# Database connection details
DB_NAME = "xyz"
DB_USER = "user"
DB_PASSWORD = "0000"
DB_HOST = "localhost"
DB_PORT = "5432"

# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# Flask application
app = Flask(__name__)
asgi_app = WsgiToAsgi(app)  # Wrap the Flask app with WsgiToAsgi adapter

# Database connection function

type here

def get_db_connection():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=DB_NAME,
            user=DB_USER,
            password=DB_PASSWORD,
            host=DB_HOST,
            port=DB_PORT
        )
        return conn
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Database connection error: {e}")
        return None

# Handle incoming webhook events from Stripe
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    payload = request.get_data(as_text=True)
    sig_header = request.headers.get('Stripe-Signature')

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret)
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        logging.error(f"Invalid payload: {e}")
        return jsonify(success=False), 400
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        logging.error(f"Signature verification failed: {e}")
        return jsonify(success=False), 400

    # Handle the event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']
        chat_id = session['client_reference_id']
        amount_total = session['amount_total']
        
        # Infer the subscription plan based on the amount
        subscription_plan = 'Weekly' if amount_total == 695 else 'Monthly' if amount_total == 1995 else 'Unknown'

        # Update the database with subscription information
        conn = get_db_connection()
        if conn is not None:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            try:
                cursor.execute(
                    "UPDATE user_subscription SET subscription_plan = %s WHERE chat_id = %s",
                    (subscription_plan, chat_id)
                )
                conn.commit()
                logging.info(f"Updated subscription plan for chat_id {chat_id}")
            except Exception as e:
                logging.error(f"Database error: {e}")
            finally:
                cursor.close()
                conn.close()
        else:
            logging.error("Failed to connect to the database.")

    return jsonify(success=True), 200

# Handle GET requests to retrieve subscription data
@app.route('/subscription/<int:chat_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_subscription(chat_id):
    conn = get_db_connection()
    if conn is not None:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT chat_id, subscription_plan FROM user_subscription WHERE chat_id = %s",
                (chat_id,)
            )
            result = cursor.fetchone()
            if result:
                response = {
                    "chat_id": result[0],
                    "subscription_plan": result[1]
                }
                return jsonify(response), 200
            else:
                return jsonify({"error": "Subscription not found"}), 404
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Database error: {e}")
            return jsonify({"error": "Database error"}), 500
        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()
    else:
        logging.error("Failed to connect to the database.")
        return jsonify({"error": "Database connection error"}), 500

# Index route for testing
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Perfectly Working'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from uvicorn import run
    run(asgi_app, host='0.0.0.0', port=4242)



I see you're trying to construct the event (using the payload, signature header, and endpoint secret) but I don't see where you're defining endpoint_secret in your code. Don't share the secret here (as it should be a secret) but I recommend starting there.

really appreciate the input , I figured it out anyways ,
what i did is passed the ChatID as client reference ID and created a new customer ID for that chat ID in my tg_bot.py. Which allowed me to save the customer ID and chatID both and can listen to it via webhooks

yes you can pass it. here how i m passing it.

This is my API in django. The variable
    try:
        checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price': f'{price}',
                    'quantity': seats,
                },
            ],
            payment_method_types=['card', ],
            mode='subscription',
            success_url=settings.SITE_URL + 'payment?success=true&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
            cancel_url=settings.SITE_URL + 'payment?canceled=true',

        # Here you can send telegramChatID
            metadata={
                "price_id": f'{price}',        
                "email": f"{request.user.email}",
                "seats": f"{seats}",
                "yearly": f"{yearly}",
                "monthly": f"{monthly}"
            }
        )

        redirect_url = checkout_session.url
        return Response(data=redirect_url, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except Exception as e:
        return Response({'error': 'Something went wrong when creating stripe checkout session'},
                        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

And now in your webhook when checkout.session.completed will call you can get like this here is my an API:
class WebhookApiView(APIView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        payload = request.data

        event_type = payload.get('type')
        if event_type == "checkout.session.completed":
            seats = payload.get('data', {}).get('object', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('seats')
            price_id = payload.get('data', {}).get('object', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('price_id')
            email = payload.get('data', {}).get('object', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('email')
            yearly = payload.get('data', {}).get('object', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('yearly')
            monthly = payload.get('data', {}).get('object', {}).get('metadata', {}).get('monthly')
            subscription_id = payload.get('data').get('object')['subscription']
            user = User.objects.get(email=email)
            # remaining code comes here

if you want to test it locally you have to use stripe cli:
Run this command in your terminal:
 stripe listen --forward-to http://0.0.0.0:8000/app/webhook/ it will automaically call your webhook API when checkout session complete.
